# Which version of Mathematica has cursor animation when running on Windows?

Tags: front-end

Does anyone remember which version of *Mathematica*, running under Windows, has the following behavior: when you type something into a front-end window, the cursor has a small animation? It becomes bigger and then shrinks back to the normal cursor.

I miss that beautiful GUI behavior and was wondering if I can get it back (or at least have a preference item that will make it happen again).

It must be one of the 5/6/7 version, I think.

Comment: When you say "type something" do you mean "hit a key" (or a combinaison of keys) or entering normal text (or code) ?

Comment: @andre Yes, that's exactly what I meant.